# how to Find Maximum and minimum entry time of a specific day from table?

Tags: c#, sql-server, time

my current project is to create employee in out table. I am having raw data with several entry for a single employee. my objective is to find the first and the last time of that specific day. My question is how can I find it?[image]

Comment: My question is: what have you tried?

Comment: Are you trying to find Min, Max on a particular day, for a **single employee or all employees in the table**

Comment: for a single employee......

Comment: MUG4N, I am out of idea and didn't face anything bfore..

Answer (score 1):

```
select min(time_column) as min_time, 
       max(time_column) as max_time
from your_table
where date_column = '2014-04-06'
```